# How do I make these 3 very similar functions shorter

Tags: javascript, html, css

> Hello so today I was curios how would I code smarter and shorter. here is litle project I did like 2 weeks ago:

```js
 // Get input element
    let filterInput = document.getElementById('filterInput');
    // Add event listener
    filterInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);

    function filterNames(){
      // Get value of input
      let filterValue = document.getElementById('filterInput').value.toUpperCase();

      // Get names ul
      let ul = document.getElementById('names');
      // Get lis from ul
      let li = ul.querySelectorAll('li.collection-item');

      // Loop through collection-item lis
      for(let i = 0;i < li.length;i++){
        let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        // If matched
        if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1){
          li[i].style.display = '';
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

    }

    function do1(){
      var input = document.getElementById('ipt1').value;
      var a = document.createElement('a');
          a.setAttribute('href', '#');
          a.textContent = input;
      var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.setAttribute('class', 'collection-item');
          a.onclick=function(){
            var div = this.parentElement;
            div.style.display = "none";
      }
      var div = document.getElementById('div1');
        li.appendChild(a);
        div1.appendChild(li)
        if(input===""){
          alert('please fill in information');
          return false;
        }
  
    }

    function do2(){
      var input = document.getElementById('ipt2').value;
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.setAttribute('href', '#');
      a.textContent = input;
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.setAttribute('class', 'collection-item');
      a.onclick=function(){
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.display = "none";
      }
      var div = document.getElementById('div2');
      li.appendChild(a);
      div2.appendChild(li);
    
    }

     function do3(){
      var input = document.getElementById('ipt3').value;
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.setAttribute('href', '#');
      a.textContent = input;
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.setAttribute('class', 'collection-item');
      a.onclick=function(){
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.display = "none";
      }
      var div = document.getElementById('div3');
      li.appendChild(a);
      div3.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.css">
  <title>My Contacts</title>
</head>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="center-align">
      My Contacts
    </h1>
    <input type="text" id="filterInput" placeholder="Search names...">
    <ul id="names" class="collection with-header">
      <li class="collection-header">
        <h5>A</h5> <input class="ipt" type="box" id="ipt1"><button onclick="do1();">click me to add another name</button>
      </li>
   <div id="div1">   
    
   </div>  
      <li class="collection-header">
        <h5>B</h5> <input class="ipt" type="box" id="ipt2"><button onclick="do2();"> click me to add another name</button>
      </li>
    <div id="div2">  

     </div> 
      <li class="collection-header">
        <h5>C</h5> <input class="ipt" type="box" id="ipt3"><button onclick="do3();"> click me to add another name</button>
      </li>
    <div id="div3">  
     </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

> So as you can see there are 3 functions that are literally same but just have diffrent id's and that kind of stuff. How do I shorten these 3 function is there any way? I searched little bit about prototype, because I've heard that prototypes have something to do with shortening code and making it easier to understand and much more shorter. So if you have any ideas please leave a comment I would appreaciate it. And one more question: should I start learning javascript OOP. I don't really know if it's important to learn or not?

Answer (score 1):

Make one function and take in some parameters:

```
function doTheThing(idA, idB){
  var input = document.getElementById(idA).value;
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', '#');
  a.textContent = input;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.setAttribute('class', 'collection-item');
  a.onclick=function(){
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
  var div = document.getElementById(idB);
  li.appendChild(a);
  div.appendChild(li);   
}
```

Also, your variables `div1`, `div2`, and `div3` are not defined, they are the IDs that you are using. Call them all with `var div` as shown above.

Comment: Why was I downvoted? I clearly answered the question, and feedback on how to make my answer more clear would be helpful.

Comment: If I was going to guess .. it's probably for re-declaring `a` locally

Comment: @Tibrogargan  Oh whoops, I just named the parameter a quick name and didn't notice. Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote either, but `do` is a reserved word and you can't use it as the name of a function - it'll throw an error.

Comment: @JonUleis Thanks again! Community is what I'm here for.

Comment: Also .. you didn't start it, but 'a' and 'b' are terrible names and you haven't handled the 'alert` in do1

Comment: @Tibrogargan The point of my answer was to explain how to reduce the three methods, not rewrite the whole thing for the OP. The concept is there and if the OP wants he/she may rename the variables and handle the alert that should be attached to the bottom of the function.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of down voting with no explanation going on.  C'est la vie.  Still, no reason to continue a bad practice you know is bad.  Although, admittedly I could have gone to more effort in the re-write department myself.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to your function that allows you to pass the bit that differs between each instance.

Here's a working demo where the function `addName` takes a number which is concatenated with your div/ipt names.

```js
// Get input element
let filterInput = document.getElementById('filterInput');
// Add event listener
filterInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);

function filterNames() {
  // Get value of input
  let filterValue = document.getElementById('filterInput').value.toUpperCase();
  // Get names ul
  let ul = document.getElementById('names');
  // Get lis from ul
  let li = ul.querySelectorAll('li.collection-item');
  // Loop through collection-item lis
  for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    // If matched
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = '';
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}

function addName(num) {
  var input = document.getElementById('ipt' + num).value;
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', '#');
  a.textContent = input;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.setAttribute('class', 'collection-item');
  a.onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (input === "") {
    alert('please fill in information');
    return false;
  }
  var div = document.getElementById('div' + num);
  li.appendChild(a);
  div.appendChild(li)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.css">
  <title>My Contacts</title>
</head>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="center-align">
    My Contacts
  </h1>
  <input type="text" id="filterInput" placeholder="Search names...">
  <ul id="names" class="collection with-header">
    <li class="collection-header">
      <h5>A</h5> <input class="ipt" type="box" id="ipt1"><button onclick="addName(1);">click me to add another name</button>
    </li>
    <div id="div1">

    </div>
    <li class="collection-header">
      <h5>B</h5> <input class="ipt" type="box" id="ipt2"><button onclick="addName(2);"> click me to add another name</button>
    </li>
    <div id="div2">

    </div>
    <li class="collection-header">
      <h5>C</h5> <input class="ipt" type="box" id="ipt3"><button onclick="addName(3);"> click me to add another name</button>
    </li>
    <div id="div3">
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

When you're doing this, the first place to start is by parameterizing the differences.  A very quick and dirty way to do this would be something like this:

```
function doit(index, nonEmptyInput) {
    // assumption: code calling this function will not use an invalid/null value for index
    var input = document.getElementById('ipt'+index).value;
    if (nonEmptyInput && input === "") {
        alert('please fill in information');
        return false;
    }
    // input is valid
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    a.textContent = input;
    a.onclick = function() {
        this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.setAttribute('class', 'collection-item');
    li.appendChild(a);
    document.getElementById('div'+index).appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is an example of a few things you can do to simply shorten the code itself.

Also, I haven't read over all of your code, but your use `let` is fairly lenient so to speak. You should be using `const` in some scenarios.

```
// you can remove most semi-colons for starters
const filterInput = document.getElementById('filterInput')

// no need for event listener, unless you plan on using the event more than once
filterInput.onkeyup = () => {

  // can reuse global variable which is declared above
  let filterValue = filterInput.value.toUpperCase()

  // here you can combine the selectors into one variable
  let li = document.getElementById('names').querySelectorAll('li.collection-item')

  // let is not necessarily necessary
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]

    // can use ternary operator instead of if/else statement
    li[i].style.display = a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1 ? '' : 'none'
  }
}

...
```